# php read txt file with space

Tags: php

I read a txt file in php. The problem is I could except the space from it. I used explode() function but It doesn't work. I tried all of the ways to read but nothing right.

```
$a = file_get_contents($file_url, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$a = explode(" ",$a);//When I call this, all of value are added to $a[0] as an array
$a = explode("\n",$a[0]); // I called this to explode "enter" but it doesn't work too
```

And now, after call the codes above, $a[0] is "85", $a[1] is "94   16". When I call $a[1][0], it's "9" instead "94" as I want.

The data at txt file is a triangle as the problem in IOI 1994:

```
85
94 16
15 63 72
55 78 89 105
77 24 56 93 17
...
```

This is the file which I want to use http://www.mediafire.com/?kjdjflvf0665q03

And this is my code to solve the problem triangle with this data from txt file

```
$t = array();
$count = 0;
$l = strlen($a[0]);
$d = 0;//get the quantity of rows in txt file
while($l>0){
    $d++;
    $l = $l - $d;
}
$f = array();
$prevX = $prevY = $val = 0;
//add all of values to array $t[] as a type: $t[row][col]
for($i =0 ; $i<$d; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<=$i; $j++){
        $t[$i][$j] = $a[0][$count++];
    }
}
//start the beginning points: $f[row+1][col] = ($t[row+1][col]+MAX(f[row][col],f[row][col-1]),prevX, prevY, $t[row+1][col]) 
$f[0][0] = array($t[0][0],$prevX,$prevY, $t[0][0]);
$f[1][0] = array(($t[1][0]+$f[0][0][0]),0,0,$t[1][0]);
$f[1][1] = array(($t[1][1]+$f[0][0][0]),0,0,$t[1][1]);
$i=2;
while($i<$d){
    for ( $j=0; $j <= $i; $j++ ){
        if(($j-1)<0){//check to except the value which not undefined, but may be not works exactly
            $f[$i][$j] = array(($f[$i-1][$j][0]+$t[$i][$j]),$i-1,$j,$t[$i][$j]);
        }
        else {
            if($j>($i-1)){//check to except the value which not undefined, but may be not works exactly
                $f[$i][$j] = array(($f[$i-1][$j-1][0]+$t[$i][$j]),$i-1,$j-1,$t[$i][$j]);
            }
            else{ 
                if($f[$i-1][$j][0]<$f[$i-1][$j-1][0]){
                    $f[$i][$j] = array(($f[$i-1][$j-1][0]+$t[$i][$j]),$i-1,$j-1,$t[$i][$j]);
                }
                else if($f[$i-1][$j][0]>$f[$i-1][$j-1][0]){
                    $f[$i][$j] = array(($f[$i-1][$j][0]+$t[$i][$j]),$i-1,$j,$t[$i][$j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
//print_r($f);
$result=0;
$x = $y = $finalR = 0;
for($j=0;$j<$d;$j++){
    if($f[$d-1][$j][0]>$result){
        $result = $f[$d-1][$j][0];
        $x = $d-1;
        $y = $j;
        $finalR = $f[$d-1][$j][3];
    }
}
while($x>0){
    echo '(',$x,',',$y,')',$f[$x][$y][3],'<----';
    $x = $f[$x][$y][1];
    $y = $f[$x][$y][2];
}
echo '(0,0)', $f[0][0][3];
```

Comment: Please include the content of the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to have $a[1] as "94 16" and have $a[1][0] as 94 because $a[1] is string and the $a[1] in $a[1][0] is an array key.

It's easy enough to make two arrays, one for the row and one for the reference table

```
<?
$file = file('file.txt');
foreach($file as $i => $line)
{
    foreach(explode("\t",$line) as $num)
    {
        $num = trim($num);
        if($num!='')
        {
            $a[$i][] = $num;
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
pre($a);

//full rows examples
pre(get_ref('0',$a));
pre(get_ref('1',$a));
pre(get_ref('2',$a));

//individual cells examples
pre(get_ref('0,0',$a));
pre(get_ref('1,0',$a));
pre(get_ref('1,1',$a));
pre(get_ref('2,0',$a));
pre(get_ref('2,1',$a));
pre(get_ref('3,2',$a));

function get_ref($ref,$a)
{
    $ref = explode(',',$ref);
    foreach($ref as $r)
    {
        $a = $a[$r];
    }
    if(is_array($a))
    {
        return(implode("\t",$a));
    }else{
        return($a);
    }

}


function pre($d)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($d);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, I got it. But now when I run it, I got this:
Notice: Undefined offset: ... in C:\...\myfile.php on line ... What should I do???

Comment: Cause the code which I use to add $f value. At While Loops after I start the beginning points

Comment: The value of $f[252][116][0] is 88, $f[252][116][1] is 251 (prevX), $f[252][116][2] is 115 (prevY). But the value of $f[251][115][0] is undefined. I don't know why. You can copy my code and run it by cmd.

Comment: OK, are there any other 'navigation' rules like nextX and nextY?

Comment: at the position [ i ][ j ], we could only go to [ i+1 ][ j ] or [ i+1 ][ j+1 ] It means just go down to the right only

Comment: Please explain the previous X and Y as I don't get that at all. I can see that 252,116 is the 116th value on line 252 but after that I don't see 115 anywhere in the file.

Comment: because we just only go down to right so when we turn back. If we want to go to position 252.116, we must at 251.115 or 251.116. prevX and prevY are used to save the position which is larger than when we compare the value at 251.115 and 251.116 So that when we got the result, we could turn back to have a longest road from the start to the end

Comment: Got it, I found out that the value of $t [ i ][ j ] at firstly and after run while loops was changed. I don't know why...

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot,Mr.Andy